# 'MyApp' has stopped and forcing to close

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, camera

I'm developing Android app on Android studio using Opencv library and when I try to open my app it opens then right after that it closes and displaying crash message. I'm new on mobile development

Using : OpenCV310, Android Studio 3.0,

```
public class ScanLicensePlateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected AnylineOcrScanView scanView;
private LicensePlateResultView licensePlateResultView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set the flag to keep the screen on (otherwise the screen may go dark during scanning)
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anyline_ocr);

    String license = getString(R.string.anyline_license_key);
    // Get the view from the layout
    scanView = (AnylineOcrScanView) findViewById(R.id.scan_view);
    // Configure the view (cutout, the camera resolution, etc.) via json
    // (can also be done in xml in the layout)
    scanView.setConfig(new AnylineViewConfig(this, "license_plate_view_config.json"));

    // Copies given traineddata-file to a place where the core can access it.
    // This MUST be called for every traineddata file that is used
    // (before startScanning() is called).
    // The file must be located directly in the assets directory
    // (or in tessdata/ but no other folders are allowed)
    scanView.copyTrainedData("tessdata/GL-Nummernschild-Mtl7_uml.traineddata",
            "8ea050e8f22ba7471df7e18c310430d8");
    scanView.copyTrainedData("tessdata/Arial.traineddata", "9a5555eb6ac51c83cbb76d238028c485");
    scanView.copyTrainedData("tessdata/Alte.traineddata", "f52e3822cdd5423758ba19ed75b0cc32");
    scanView.copyTrainedData("tessdata/deu.traineddata", "2d5190b9b62e28fa6d17b728ca195776");

    // Configure the OCR for license plate scanning via a custom script file
    // This is how you could add custom scripts optimized by Anyline for your use-case
    AnylineOcrConfig anylineOcrConfig = new AnylineOcrConfig();
    anylineOcrConfig.setCustomCmdFile("license_plates.ale");

    // set the ocr config
    scanView.setAnylineOcrConfig(anylineOcrConfig);

    // initialize with the license and a listener
    scanView.initAnyline(license, new AnylineOcrListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReport(String identifier, Object value) {
            // Called with interesting values, that arise during processing.
            // Some possibly reported values:
            //
            // $brightness - the brightness of the center region of the cutout as a float value
            // $confidence - the confidence, an Integer value between 0 and 100
            // $thresholdedImage - the current image transformed into black and white
            // $sharpness - the detected sharpness value (only reported if minSharpness > 0)
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTextOutlineDetected(List<PointF> list) {
            // Called when the outline of a possible text is detected.
            // If false is returned, the outline is drawn automatically.
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResult(AnylineOcrResult result) {
            // Called when a valid result is found
            String results[] = result.getText().split("-");
            String licensePlate = results[1];

            licensePlateResultView.setLicensePlate(licensePlate);
            licensePlateResultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAbortRun(AnylineOcrError code, String message) {
            // Is called when no result was found for the current image.
            // E.g. if no text was found or the result is not valid.
        }
    });


    // disable the reporting if set to off in preferences
    if (!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(
            SettingsFragment.KEY_PREF_REPORTING_ON, true)) {
        // The reporting of results - including the photo of a scanned meter -
        // helps us in improving our product, and the customer experience.
        // However, if you wish to turn off this reporting feature, you can do it like this:
        scanView.setReportingEnabled(false);
    }
    addLicensePlateResultView();
}

private void addLicensePlateResultView() {
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    licensePlateResultView = new LicensePlateResultView(this);
    licensePlateResultView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mainLayout.addView(licensePlateResultView, params);
    licensePlateResultView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startScanning();

        }
    });
}

private void startScanning() {
    licensePlateResultView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    // this must be called in onResume, or after a result to start the scanning again
    scanView.startScanning();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startScanning();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    scanView.cancelScanning();
    scanView.releaseCameraInBackground();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (licensePlateResultView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        startScanning();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

### source code is here.
If possible please help.

[Logcat error shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgxpi.png)

Comment: clean, rebuild, restart, 
check build.graddle for "multiDexEnabled true", "compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'"

Comment: maybe you did not call [setCameraOpenListener(CameraOpenListener listener)](https://documentation.anyline.com/api/android/at/nineyards/anyline/camera/CameraView.html#setCameraOpenListener-at.nineyards.anyline.camera.CameraOpenListener-)? The doc explicitly says that in this case, a RuntimeException will be fired.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally more information regarding the error would be best i.e the opencv library version etc. Given it seems to be an Android issue, I would advise

1. File and issue or view [issues](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+android) pertaining to this error on their github page. Search for related Android errors to see if they match.
2. IF you cannot find a related error, file an issue there.